# What is the maximum player running speed?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

What is the fastest running speed for a character and how can it be achieved?

Comment: It seems 6.32m/s (~23km/h) for a standing sprint with a pistol [link](https://battlegrounds.gamepedia.com/Movement_Speed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Movement Speed in *PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds* is determined by what weapon you are currently holding, as well as your current stance, plus any level 3 or 4 boosts from consumables (Energy Drinks, Pills, Adrenaline).

To break it down fastest to slowest:
Sprinting Player (holstered weapon) with Tier 4 boost = **6.7 m/s** (+6.2% speed)
Sprinting Player (holstered weapon) with Tier 3 boost = **6.4 m/s** (+2.5% speed)
Base Sprinting Player (holstered weapon) speed = **6.3 m/s**

**So, at your speediest it will take around 15 seconds to cross one white square (100m) of flat terrain.**
So put your gun away and start chugging those pills and energy drinks if you gotta go fast.

([source](https://forums.tiny-spaceship.com/t/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-an-ocd-thread/25?u=magnumdopus), all speeds rounded to 2 significant digits)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run fast, you'll need to holster your weapon (you'll run slightly faster by doing it).
On your minimap, you'll notice a grid. At your maximum running speed, you can go through an entire square in approximately 16 seconds (in a straight line from one side to the other).

Comment: Did you think about boosters? (Energy Drink, etc...)

Comment: No, I did not, i'll test it asap !